# WARNING: Apache doesn't seem to be compiled with the 'prefork', 'worker' or 'event' MPM - Rails - Apache2 - Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, deployment, passenger

I am deploying a Rails application on an ubuntu server that has Apache2 installed, Rails installed, and I am trying to get the application deployed using Passenger.

Apache is installed just fine - I can view static files, reload it, start it, stop it, etc..
Rails is installed just fine - I can run the WeBrick server from the application root.
Now I want to use passenger to deploy.

When I run the following command:

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

It goes through some stuff then the following error comes up:

```
WARNING: Apache doesn't seem to be compiled with the 'prefork', 'worker' or 'event' MPM - Rails - Apache2 - Passenger
```

Basically, the Passenger installer tells me to recompile Apache with one of those MPM's or continue the installation process. I tried continue but it fails.

So, how do I got about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Fix Apache. How to fix this depends on how you installed Apache in the first place. If you installed Apache by installing it from source, then reinstall Apache by compiling it from source, but this time using the worker MPM. Refer to the Apache documentation to learn how to do that.
2. Don't use Apache. Instead, use Phusion Passenger + Nginx, or use Phusion Passenger Standalone.

Comment: Thanks ! I am really considering nginx. However, id like to figure out this problem. Could you give a quick example of recompiling and a resource, please?

Comment: BTW - I did try doing the nginx route - it also failed. I think they are failing because I am trying to use AWS pre-packaged image that has git, apache, nginx, ruby, php, etc all installed already. I tried a new image and all the installation worked fine. However, now when it completes, I cannot find nginx. I posted a new question.

Comment: The official Apache documentation teaches you how to compile it. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html